# mostrar posts de personas que sigo php

Tags: php, mysql

estoy creando una red social, estoy creando el apartado del feed pero tengo un problema. Básicamente quiero imprimir los posts de las personas que el usuario sigue, no sé como hacer que imprima de todos los usuarios que sigue, solo me imprime el de 1 usuario.

Tabla followers (seguidores)
[image]

Tabla posts (publicaciones)
[image]

Tabla users
[image]

Codigo:

```php
 $followerPost = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT following FROM users u INNER JOIN follow f ON u.id = f.following WHERE f.follower = '$userid'");
    $asdasd = mysqli_fetch_array($followerPost);
    $following = $asdasd['following'];

    $qu = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM posts INNER JOIN users ON posts.author = users.id WHERE users.id = '$following' ORDER BY posts.post_id DESC LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset} ");

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qu)) {
   //aquí se imprimen los posts
}
```

Comment: Puedes poner la estructura de las tablas?? se me hace difícil hacer una prueba sin saber los campos de cada tabla. **Puede ser una imagen de cada tabla para ver el tipo de dato guardado también**

Comment: @OCHOA editado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo quieres imprimir los posts de las personas que el usuario (para el ejemplo y según tu tabla el usuario **David Mc**) sigue y que **$userid** guarda el ID (1) de ese usuario.

Después veo que en tu tabla followers esta el campo **following** que hace referencia al ID de cada usuario al que David sigue.

No entiendo porque en tu primer query no haces algo mas simple, como extraer todos los "following" del usuario en cuestión, y creas un array con todos los ID de esos usuarios al que David sigue. A parte que en tu query estas haciendo un **SELECT following FROM users** cuando users no tiene ese campo.

```
$query = "SELECT following FROM followers WHERE follower = '$userid'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$arraIDs = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        array_push($arraIDs, $row[0]);
}
$IDs = implode(', ', $arraIDs);

echo $IDs; // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Una vez que tienes los IDs de todos a los que David sigue, puedes fácilmente consultar todos los posts de esos IDs y mostrarlos

```
$qu = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE author IN ($IDs) ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset}");

$rows = $result2->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['text'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! me ha funcionado y me has sacado un dolor de cabeza jajaja

Comment: Que bueno. Me alegra